# Windows audio not enabled on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, audio, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo Yoga 2, and the Windows Audio is not enabled. I have tried enabling it, but it gives me an error code 0x800706cc. I don't think it has anything to do with AVG. I don't know what else to do...

Comment: Have you checked the AVG quarantine? Is AVG even installed on your computer? Anything in the event logs that might help?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [AVG might be the problem](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-hardware/windows-audio-cant-be-started-error-1740/d94003a0-aee9-44a0-9d0d-a8931fd45462)

Check out the link and see if this matches the error you are getting. I fso, AVG may be quarantining files that it shouldn't.